# How to group tasks with parent task in SharePoint 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I have some workflows in SP2010 with multiple and sometimes many steps.

In order to make the view easier to read for the user I would like to group them all under the initiation task.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to split your long workflow into several smaller workflows. Each small workflow could launch the next part, if it completes with a success.